# What happens if have come after modals with "each"?

Tags: modal-verbs

Each user can have or
Each user can  has ?
which one is correct I have seen them both

Comment: "I can has cheeseburger" is the way it is said only in the nonstandard lolcatz conlang.

Comment: In standard English, you must use *have*.

Comment: *I have seen them both* -- I wonder where...

Comment: Can + have only, this is correct traditional English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modal verbs** are always followed by a **bare infinitive** (read, be, have, see, fly, run and e.t.c)

The correct is **"Each user can have"** (*can* + bare infinitive *have*)

If you don't place a modal verb then "Each user *has*"

Comment: Yes, but I think it's worth mentioning that *ought* takes to-infinitive.(However some books consider *ought to* a single unit).

Comment: @user178049 **Ought** is a semi-modal verb and there are other rules for semi-modals. **Ought** and **used** always take the "to"+infinitive. **"Dare"** when used as a modal verb, takes a bare infinitive. **Need** is also followed by a bare infinitive when modal. As a main verb they may or may not be followed by "to"+infinitive.

Comment: Semi-modals are normally fixed expressions such as *have to*, *had better*, *be supposed to*. Dare, need, and ought to are marginal modals.

Comment: This is a neverlasting discussion, you can look this up in different grammar books and they might all give different information.

Comment: I think that's a new grammar conception that puts them in the same category. But I am—as traditional grammar worshipper, I'm not familiar with those newer generalizations(and I still distinguish gerund and participle). But if you follow The Teacher's Grammar of English, yes, undisputably, semi-modals and marginal modals are basically two different things.